# run ajax without authorization headers

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to create ajax call with authorization headears only when user writes username and password. When this vars are empty I need to create ajax call without authorization headers. How can I do this? Can I make it with one ajax or I need to create two ajax every for one situation?

```
var username = "user123";
var password = "pass123";

//var username = "";
//var password = "";    

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url_survey,
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
        'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
        },
        success: 
          function (data) {
            alert("SUCCESS");
       },
        error:
          function (data) {
            alert("ERROR");
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var username = "user123";
var password = "pass123";

//var username = "";
//var password = "";    
var headers = {}; //list of headers

if(username && password) //user and pass exists
    headers['Authorization'] = "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password);

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url_survey,
        dataType: "json",
        headers: headers, //use our headers
        success: 
          function (data) {
            alert("SUCCESS");
       },
        error:
          function (data) {
            alert("ERROR");
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter passed to `$.ajax` is just an object.  Just simply create it, add properties as needed, then send it to `$.ajax.

```
var ajaxData = {
    type: "GET",
    url: url_survey,
    dataType: "json",
    success: 
      function (data) {
        alert("SUCCESS");
   },
    error:
      function (data) {
        alert("ERROR");
      }
};

if(username  && password){
    ajaxData.headers = {
        'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
    };
}

$.ajax(ajaxData);
```